# calling a bat file in C# IIS does nothing

Tags: c#, batch-file, iis

I have a C# program that is trying to call a bat file in the project folder. Here is the code which is calling the bat file:

```
protected void btnHotFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Abbyy_Script/restart-hotfolder.bat");
        startInfo.FileName = path;
        Process.Start(startInfo);
        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Batch file error");
        log.Error(ex.InnerException.Message);
        log.Error(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

I have read on the forum that some have suggested giving the IIS user folder access rights to the folder containing the bat file. Tried but no avail..

This is part of the project structure showing where the bat file resides:

project - Abbyy_Script - restart-hotfolder.bat

In the bat file, I am currently testing it with notepad++ exe:

```
taskkill /im notepad++.exe
TIMEOUT 2
START "" "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

Comment: Your code hase more issues: UseShellExecute = false with Verb = runas" makes no sense. A batch file is not an executable so you'll have to call it with smt. like 'cmd /k file.bat' when UseShellExecute = false. But the most important thing: you can't start interactive programs like notepad++ from a non-interactive service process. How do you even wan't to start a (winforms ?) app from IIS?

Comment: I would start testing with something easier than a bat file with taskkill. Something like "echo hi >> testfile.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You should improve your batch file:

```
taskkill /f /im notepad++.exe /t
timeout /t 2 /nobreak

IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" (
    start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
)
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" (
    start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
)
```

The C# code needs to be improved too:

```
protected void btnHotFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Abbyy_Script/restart-hotfolder.bat");
        startInfo.FileName = path;
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Batch file error");
        log.Error(ex.InnerException.Message);
        log.Error(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the comments! I needed to use this method to automate a process in Abbyy hotfolder.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?